# Change clock source in kernel stanza

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I want to permanently change clock source in CentOS 7. I Found quite nice article here: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18627

```
Permanently, adding clocksource= to the kernel stanza:

title Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (2.6.32-71.18.2.el6.x86_64)
    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.18.2.el6.x86_64 ro root=LABEL=/ crashkernel=auto 
    clocksource=acpi_pm
    initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-71.18.2.el6.x86_64.img
```

But I don't know what is kernel stanza and how to add this into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your link is referring to is GRUB Boot Loader configuration file.  It's usually located in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`

> GRUB's configuration file, /boot/grub/grub.conf, contains a few lines with directives, such as default, timeout, splashimage and hiddenmenu (the last directive has no argument). The remainder of the file contains 4-line stanzas that each refer to an installed kernel. These stanzas always start with a title entry, after which the associated root, kernel and initrd directives should always be indented. Ensure that each stanza starts with a title that contains a version number (in parentheses) that matches the version number in the kernel /vmlinuz-<version_number> line of the same stanza.

The reference you supplied is stating to add `clocksource=acpi_pm` to the end of the `kernel` line for the specific kernel you're using.

**For Centos 7:**

I'm assuming you're using a MBR system...if you're using a UEFI-based system the commands are different.

Backup your `grub` and `grub.cfg` files

```
# cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub-backup
# cp /boot/grub2/grub.cfg /boot/grub2/grub.cfg-backup
```

Then edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX line in /etc/default/grub file and add the `clocksource=acpi_pm` like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 crashkernel=auto console=ttyS0,115200 clocksource=acpi_pm"
```

Save the file and run the following command:

```
# grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Then reboot your server.

Prior to modifying the /etc/default/grub:

> # cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
>   xen

After modification:

> # cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
>   acpi_pm

**Reference**

[Verifying the Boot Loader](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-kernel-boot-loader)
[How to Modify Kernel Command Line](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-modify-the-kernel-command-line/)

Comment: Thanks but I didn't find /boot/grub/grub.conf. I have grub.cfg in grub2 but there is a note that it is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub. I saw this files and didn't find anything similar to kernel stanza...

Comment: @Mateusz I updated the info to include Centos 7 and tested it on an instance I have.  Pretty straightforward, let me know how it goes.

Comment: We made it! Thank you so much! :)